# Sublime text 3 - ColorHighlighter not working "live"

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have successfully installed package [ColorHighlighter](https://github.com/Monnoroch/ColorHighlighter) in Sublime text 3, but for some reason it is not working automatically.

For example, if I edit new or existing CSS file and add:

```
.someclass {
    color: red
}
```

Nothing will happen. I have to go to Tools - ColorHighlighter - Highlight all style - Outlined in order to changes take effect.

Next if I continue adding the next property, I will have to go few times to Tools - ColorHighlighter and change settings few times to apply new effects.

I'm using Windows 7, Sublime 3. Imagemagick is installed.
If is of any help, I have tried this on Mac and its the same.

Maybe Im doing something wrong?

P.S. I have tried to uninstall and install package few times. No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit the ColorHighlighter settings to get it to work properly, especially if your ImageMagick directory isn't in your `PATH`. Select **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> ColorHighlighter -> Settings-User`** and add the following:

```js
{
    "enabled": true,
    "style": "filled",
    "icons": true,
    "ha_style": "filled",
    "ha_icons": true,
    "default_keybindings": true,
    // change this path to your actual path to convert.exe
    "convert_util_path" : "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick/bin/convert.exe"
}
```

making sure you have the correct path to ImageMagick's `convert.exe`. Save the file, and the settings should take effect. They'll look like this:

[image: ColorHighlighter example]

It may take a little bit of time before newly-added colors are added, so just be patient - it'll work.